# Set Value as 0 if its is Null in Angular

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-reactive-forms

I wanted to pass the value of a variable that if it is null, then automatically set its value to 0 when dispatching it in Angular

```
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [null, Validators.required],
        productPrice: [0],
        finalPrice: [0],
        remarks: [null],
    });
    
    
    onCreate(form: FormGroup) {
      console.log(form.value)
      this.store.dispatch(form.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to check the values manually using the `Array#reduce` with `Object.keys()`  function and OR `||` to use `0` when the value is `null` or `undefined`.

Try the following

```js
onCreate(form: FormGroup) {
  const value = Object.keys(form.value).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc = { ...acc, [curr]: form.value[curr] || 0 };  // update: `curr` must be `[curr]`
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));     // update: closing curly brace

  console.log(value);
  this.store.dispatch(value);
}
```

Comment: Can you check your syntax?

Comment: @Joseph: Sorry, I've updated the code. The closing brace was missing.

Comment: Its only displaying like this `curr: 1`

Comment: @Joseph: Another mistake from my side. `curr: ...` must be `[curr]:...` to interpret the value instead of the literal `curr`. Please try again.

Comment: @Joseph: Also if `||` doesn't work as expected, you could try nullish coalescing operator `??` as suggested by @Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nullish coalescing operator to return the right hand side of an argument if the left hand is null

```
const a = null;
const b = 5;

console.log( a ?? 0 ); // returns 0
console.log( b ?? 0 ); // returns 5
```

You can also use this operator with assignment `??=` if you actually want to set the left-hand side after evaluation.